# Typeahead works in the first rows but not with the jQuery rows generated

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jQuery to generate the new row when even I click the 'add' button and another jQuery typeahead to pull the data from the database so it shows out the item list, but it only works on the first line but not inside the jQuery new rows I generated. I want the jQuery code generated also have the same typeahead function like row 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjhhR.png)

this is my code for generate the rows and the typeahead

```
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'">

<td><input type="text" id="itemname'+i+'" name="itemname" placeholder="Item 
name" class="form-control border-input" /></td>

<td id="ibalance'+i+'"><div class="col-md-5"><input type="number" min="0" 
name="ibalance" id="ibalance" class="form-control border-input" 
maxlength="40"/></div></td>

<td id="quantityInHand'+i+'">0</td>

<td id="remark'+i+'"><div class="col-md-12"><input type="text" 
name="remarks" id="remark" class="form-control border-input" 
maxlength="40"/></div></td>

<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger 
btn-simple btn_remove"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></button></td>
</tr>');  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  

       $('#recipient').typeahead({
          source: function(query, result)
          {
           $.ajax({
            url:"fetch1.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{query:query},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
             result($.map(data, function(item){
              return item;
             }));
            }
           })
          }
         });

    $('#recipient').change(function(){  
        var FULL_NAME = $(this).val();  
        $.ajax({  
            url:"load_data.php",  
            method:"POST",
            dataType: "json",  
            data:{FULL_NAME:FULL_NAME},  
            success:function(data){  
                     $('#address').val(data["ADDRESS"]);
                     $('#contact').val(data["CONTACT"]);  
            }  
        });

    });


       $('#itemname1').typeahead({
          source: function(query, result)
          {
           $.ajax({
            url:"fetchItem.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{query:query},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
             result($.map(data, function(item){
              return item;
             }));
            }
           })
          }
         });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the typeahead only to the first row because of the '#itemname1' selector. What you want, is to also add it to the newly created rows. You can do that by adding the typeahead code behind the 'add' event.

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'">

        <td><input type="text" id="itemname'+i+'" name="itemname" placeholder="Item 
    name" class="form-control border-input" /></td>

    <td id="ibalance'+i+'"><div class="col-md-5"><input type="number" min="0"
    name="ibalance" id="ibalance" class="form-control border-input"
    maxlength="40"/></div></td>

    <td id="quantityInHand'+i+'">0</td>

    <td id="remark'+i+'"><div class="col-md-12"><input type="text"
                                                       name="remarks" id="remark" class="form-control border-input"
                                                       maxlength="40"/></div></td>

    <td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger 
    btn-simple btn_remove"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></button></td>
    </tr>');  

    $('#itemname' + i).typeahead({
        source: function(query, result)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"fetchItem.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{query:query},
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    result($.map(data, function(item){
                        return item;
                    }));
                }
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, it still do not display out the list like the first row. thank you for helping